# CSS absolute centering

Tags: html, css, css-position

Recently i've came across this method used to position an element both horizontally and vertically to the center. However, I wasn't able to figure out what each of the property is doing. Would someone be able to explain to me what is the effect upon setting `top:0, bottom:0, left:0, right:0`?

(Would be great if you're able to explain it using layman's term or provide an illustrative image.)

Also, what is the use of setting the display to table?

```css
.absolute-center {
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  height: auto;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<p class="absolute-center">What is this sorcery?</p>
```

Comment: to go with joel's answer, `display:table` is used as it will allow the p tag to have  a height of auto and expand to what is inside it.  If you used any other display type, it would use the `top:0;` and `bottom:0;` which would expand it to the full height of the container

Comment: http://commitstrip.com/en/2015/05/21/learning-the-hard-way also http://howtocenterincss.com/

Comment: I rolled back because I noticed the edit was approved by reviewers who accept far too easily. A snippet as a title isn't bad and is definitely better than a grammatically incorrect question.

Answer (score 44):

You can reduce the css to this:

```css
.absolute-center {
    position:absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<p class="absolute-center">What is this sorcery?</p>
```

The `absolute` element with properties like `bottom: 0; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;` will fill all the space.

So, whats the secret/sorcery here?

You are defining the width and height of the element. So, even if he wants to fill all the space he will be limited by your width and height.

The secret is the `margin: auto`, why? Because the element will fill the remain spacing with margin. That way because you have width and height defined it will have that size but the margin will fill the rest of the container/parent in the way `auto` works, equal sized both sides.

Because of the `margin:auto` you need width and height defined.

Answer (score 11):

Let's break it a bit:

If you have the following CSS (I apply it to your current markup):

```
.absolute-center {
    position:absolute;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    background: red;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

You can see that the `div.absolute-center` fills the entire parent element (in this case `body`), just by setting all properties `top`, `bottom`, `right` and `left`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0osLv27k/

So when we add `width` (additionally `height`) to the previous CSS, the element is limited to this size.

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/0osLv27k/1/

And finally the magical `margin: auto` which makes the element to be centered.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0osLv27k/2/

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add top and left positions and add transform.
If you do not need fixed width, it is no problem to delete the `width` from the css and also if your want centered text inside `p` add padding else delete it. Try this:

```css
.absolute-center {
    position:absolute;
    width: 500px;
    padding:50px 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid 1px red;
    text-align:center;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<p class="absolute-center">asdsdada</p>
```

Answer (score -4):

Check this...
HTML is

```
<p class="absolute-center"></p>
```

CSS is

```
.absolute-center {
    margin: auto;
    background: red; 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the original question about why does the CSS provided work?